# Прописная или строчная буква после многоточия, стоящего в начале предложения, написанного с красной строки (абзаца): несколько случаев

Tags: пунктуация, прописная-строчная, диалог, многоточие, абзац

Существует такое правило (см. [здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=320)):

> Если одна реплика «разрывается» другой, а затем следует продолжение
> первой реплики, то после первой ее части и перед началом второй
> ставится многоточие:
>
> — Я просил…
> — Ничего вы не просили.
> — …хотя бы минуту внимания.

Но разве это единственный случай, когда после многоточия, стоящего в начале предложения, следующего с абзаца, первая буква начинается со строчной? Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться: когда вообще нужны / не нужны многоточия и прописные/строчные буквы в следующих случаях. На что опираться при выборе решения? Или, может, хотите предложить свои случаи, примеры с готовым решением, когда после многоточия в начале предложения с красной строки следует прописная или строчная буквы?

**1.** Персонаж вслух не договаривает сказанную им фразу, но мысленно продолжает её:

*— Отстань от меня, я ещё...*

*«...Не отошёл от предыдущего раза», — хотел сказать я, но осёкся.*

**2.** Персонаж вслух не договаривает фразу, но другой персонаж её мысленно продолжает:

*— Отстань от меня, я ещё... — Он не закончил фразу.*

*«...Не отошёл от предыдущего раза», — хотел продолжить я за него, но осёкся.*

**3.** Один персонаж вслух не договаривает фразу, но другой персонаж вслух её продолжает:

*— Отстань от меня, я ещё... — Он не закончил фразу.*

*— ...Не отошёл от предыдущего раза, — продолжил я за него.*

**4.** Персонаж услышал предложение, до которого следовали другие предложения, которые он не слышал:

*Я подошёл и услышал разговор:*

*— ...Отстань от меня, я ещё... — Он не закончил фразу.*

**5.** Персонаж услышал только часть сказанного предложения:

*Я подошёл и услышал разговор:*

*— ...от меня, я ещё... — Он не закончил фразу.*

**6.** Персонаж услышал только часть сказанного предложения, причём услышал первое слово не целиком:

*Я подошёл и услышал разговор:*

*— ...ня, я ещё... — Он не закончил фразу.*